# Finding equivalence classes of an equivalence relation on $\mathcal{P(\mathbb{Z})}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, relations, equivalence-relations

We define a relation R on the set $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})$ where we let $S$ and $T$ be sets for which $S,T\in{\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})}$ and define S to be related to T if and only if there exists a bijection from S to T.

\begin{equation}
R = \bigg\{(S,T)\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})\times \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}): S\underset{\text{bijection}}{{\longrightarrow}}T\bigg\}
\end{equation}

The correspondig equivalence classes of $\{0\}$ and $P = \{2,3,5,7,...\}$ are,
\begin{align*}
\left[\{0\}\right] &= \bigg\{S\in\mathcal{P(\mathbb{Z})}: S\underset{\text{bijection}}{\longrightarrow}\{0\}\bigg\} = \bigg\{\{n\}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\bigg\}\\
\\
\left[P\right] &= \bigg\{S\in\mathcal{P(\mathbb{Z})}: S\underset{\text{bijection}}{\longrightarrow}P\bigg\} = 
\end{align*}
Now for the equivalence classes for $\{0\}$ we just have a set which contains the sets of just all individual elements in $\mathbb{Z}$ which create bijections with the set $\{0\}$. Now for the primes we have $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ itself for example since they all have same cardinality of $\aleph_0$. But now there are sets like $\{2,4,6,8,10,...\}$ and $\{1,3,5,7,9,...\}$ and ... there are an infinite number of elements in $\mathcal{P(\mathbb{Z})}$ which form a bijection with the primes or have same cardinality if you wish. Is this correct? For the primes what should I include all such sets should I just write that the equivalence relation of the primes is the set of sets which have same cardinality as $\aleph_0$?

Comment: Any infinite subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ is in a bijection with $\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: I know that already thats what I have basically already written, but then would I say that the equivalence class of the primes is just the set of all $\textbf{infinite}$ subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$, because obviously these have the same cardinality as the naturals which have the same cardinality as the primes.

Comment: What do you think the equivalence class of $\{6,7\}$ is?

Comment: Possibly, $\{\{n,k\}:n,k\in\mathbb{Z}, \hspace{0.3em}n<k\}$. You could have $n<k$ or $n>k$ it does not matter since you can still iterate through all of them its just to avoid having a repetition of the same sets like $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,1\}$ and of course sets like $\{2,2\}$ are not an option since $\{2,2\}\notin\mathcal{P(\mathbb{Z})}$.

Comment: It sounds like you understand what the equivalence classes are. What's the task you're not sure how to complete?

Comment: How should I explicitly go about writing out the equivalence class for the primes is the other equivalence class of $/{0/}$. Also would the $/[/mathbb{Z}/]$ have the same cardinality as /mathbb{Z} my intuition tells me that it would not since we know that the power set of the integers is uncountable and has the same cardinality as the reals but the equivalence class of the integers is a subset of the power set with an infinite number of elements since you can create as many infinite sets of integers as you want forming a bijection with the set of intergers. It seems as if it would be larger.

Comment: Yes, that's a valid description. But I think you're making this way more complicated than it needs to be. Can you think of a simple description of what $\{1,2\}$ and $\{6,7\}$ have in common, that they don't have in common with, say, either $\{8\}$, or $\{2,3,4\}$?

Comment: same cardinality, there exists a bijection between them.

Comment: but i just want to figure out is the equivalence class of the integers numerically equivalent to integers, that is do they have the same cardinality?

Comment: It all comes down to just what you've learned about cardinalities and infinite sets. At least under most basic versions of set theory I'm familiar with, all infinite subsets of a countable set are also countable. That'd be a good enough answer for me.

Comment: Although when I see you say "is the equivalence class of the integers numerically equivalent to the integers" I get confused. First "numerically equivalent" isn't a term I see used, and whose meaning isn't clear. Second, I don't think this is relevant to the original question. Do you believe it is, or are you just curious? ....

Comment: But I will note that there are an uncountable number of countably infinite subsets of the integers, so the equivalence class of $\mathbb Z$ __is__ uncountable. Is that what you're asking about?

Answer (score 1):

To explicitly answer two of your questions in the comments:

- "would I say that the equivalence class of the primes is just the set of all infinite subsets of $\mathbb Z$?": Yes, that would be correct, although it is also the equivalence class of $\mathbb Z$ itself, and I personally wouldn't bother to involve the set of primes. I think it complicates things for no benefit.
- "How should I explicitly go about writing out the equivalence class for the primes ...?": You shouldn't. In fact it's most likely that you can't (although proving that something can't be done requires us to get very clear about just what 'explicitly writing' means, and let's not go there).

I'm wondering if you're coming to math from a computer programming background. In programming we're expected to write algorithms that generate things. In math you can say "It's the set of all subsets with exactly two elements", and be done.